# Extracting a string based on position of found character in R

Tags: r, text, split

I found out the positions of "oo" in the following sentence:

```
sentence <- "It is a good book. Good for first reading.
This book explains everything in Qdetail with tons of examples and exercises for practice. Good for cracking written tests on campuses and competitive exams. It is cheap so any way one can have a copy along with other books"

pos = gregexpr("oo", sentence)
```

I got the result as

```
> pos
[[1]]
[1]  10  15  21  50 136 263
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 2 2 2 2 2 2
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

Based on the result, I want to extract 10 characters from each position (5 before the position and 5 after the position)

For an example,
I should get result for first location as
"s a good bo"
And I want this extraction for each and every position.
As I am new to R I couldn't figure out much how to do.
Please help me out with this.

What should I do if I have to extract the words like it is shown below:
I should get "a good book" for the first instance of matching

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `substring` after `unlist`ing the `gregexpr` output.

```
v1 <- unlist(gregexpr("oo", sentence))
substring(sentence, v1 - 5, v1 +5)
#[1] "s a good bo" "ood book. G" "ok. Good fo" "his book ex" "ce. Good fo" "her books"
```

Comment: Heyy akrun for the above mentioned problem if I want to extract the two words before and after the word which contains the phrase what should I do?

For an example I should get "a good book" for the first instance of matching.

Comment: @Maddy It is not that clear.  The first match would be for good with `"oo"`.  It is better to post as a new question.

Answer (score 5):

You could also do

```
mapply(
  substr, 
  x=sentence, 
  start=pos[[1]]-5, 
  stop=pos[[1]]+5, 
  USE.NAMES = F
)
# [1] "s a good bo" "ood book. G" "ok. Good fo"
# [4] "his book ex" "ce. Good fo" "her books"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for your quick responses

Comment: Heyy lukeA for the above mentioned problem if I want to extract the two words before and after the word which contains the phrase what should I do? For an example I should get "a good book" for the first instance of matching.

Comment: You should post a new question.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using stringr package

```
library(stringr)
ind<-str_locate_all(sentence,"oo")[[1]][ ,1]
str_sub(sentence,ind-5,ind+5)


[1] "s a good bo" "ood book. G" "ok. Good fo" "his book ex" "ce. Good fo" "her books"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
pos = gregexpr("oo", sentence)
```

Adjust the positions and lengths:

```
pos[[1]] <- pmax(pos[[1]] - 5, 0)
attr(pos[[1]], "match.length")[] <- 11
regmatches(sentence, pos)
#[[1]]
#[1] "s a good bo" "ood book. G" "ok. Good fo" "his book ex" "ce. Good fo" "her books"
```